# Seg Fault/Error when running problem with Petsc only in Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, petsc

I made the unfortunate decision to uninstall what I had working for petsc/gcc/macports/brew/ etc., because Valgrind wasn't working for me. I got Valgrind to work for me, reinstalled Petsc and slepc etc., but then after I successfully create my executable ./hello, I ran into this problem:

> ```
> ==25882== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
> ==25882==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
> ==25882==    at 0x103E31808: _pthread_wqthread_setup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
> ==25882==    by 0x103E31497: _pthread_wqthread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
> ==25882==    by 0x103E313FC: start_wqthread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
> ==25882==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
> ==25882==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
> ==25882==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
> ==25882==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
> ==25882==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
>
> ==25882== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==25882==    definitely lost: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==25882==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==25882==      possibly lost: 128 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==25882==    still reachable: 212,531 bytes in 1,554 blocks
> ==25882==         suppressed: 747,772 bytes in 740 blocks
> ==25882== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
> ==25882== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
> ==25882== 
> ==25882== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
> ==25882== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 2238 from 184)
> Segmentation fault: 11
> ```

My program is a simple program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i;
  PetscInitialize(&argc, &argv, NULL, NULL);
  printf("HELLO\n");
  PetscFinalize();
return 0; }
```

When I put through my program through Valgrind, I get a segmentation fault, but when I run it without Valgrind, I do not get any issues or seg faults. Valgrind issue? I get the segfault 11 when I add

```
PetscInitialize(&argc, &argv, NULL, NULL);
PetscFinalize();
```

How shall I fix this?

Comment: I've been working on this more, and I realized that I get this same error when I just use MPI_INIT. I'm using the mpi that Petsc installed for me.